# What classification would our World Unus Solum fall under?

Tags: planets, humans, space-colonization

Lore:

"Not much is known about the past of Unus Solum. What is known is scattered and fractured. Unus Solum was a planet that was subject to colonization efforts. The Ark ships that came were preparing to colonize the land when the unexpected happened. It is unknown what caused the Ships to crash but fortunately the Terraformers were able to make the planet habitable before the colonists were left to fend for themselves.

Eventually over the period of thousands of years some of the people of Unus Solum have developed complex societies with progressive Ideals, and some hold on to the monarchies of yesterday. Despite all the progress old grudges still hold and the anger is rising. If there is one human constant, conflict, and that holds no matter where they are."

The setting is kind of in the 70s for these people who have been living on Solum without knowing that they are the products of a failed colonization effort. there are airships tanks and guided missiles, we're struggling on what classification to give it whether it should be Dieselpunk or Cyberpunk since it incorporates both aspects. What would you call it?

[**Unus Solum DA page for more info.**](http://unussolum.deviantart.com/)

Comment: Depends, are there any retro-futuristic technologies and if so what are these like?

Comment: Yeah the Airships use magnetic cages (that allow heavy objects to "levitate") found in archeological dig ups of the old Terr- formers and colony ships that crashed.

Comment: I've never been a fan of fitting everything into super neat genre labels. The best use of them is to say "if you liked X, you might like Y, because it has these things in common". If you feel like the best label is "cyber-diesel-colonisation-punk", who's to say you're "wrong"?

Comment: why would it matter?

Answer (score 3):

While there are many distinct subgenres, not all works of fiction fit easily into well defined pigeon holes. To an old school traditional science-fiction buff Unus Solum would be readily embraced as 'science-fiction" without any need for further qualification. It might be described as a "lost-colony" type of story. Though because it has a mainly because a nineteen-seventies cultural ambience, with magnetic levitating airships this could attract an additional label of "retro-futuristic".

On another level it could be alternatively classified as "fantastic adventure" (although this does depend on how much "adventure" there is in this world's fictional content). "Fantastic adventures" are a wide category, but basically they are adventure stories with added fantastic elements which can be science-fictional, supernatural, occult or pseudoscientific in nature. Sometimes this includes mixtures from all departments of the fantastic. Examples of cinematic fantastic adventure are *Star Wars* and *Raiders of the Lost Ark*. It is a very broad category.

Because, or so it seems to this author, events of Unus Solum take place on the one planet this might be, yet again, characterized as "planetary romance". Edgar Rice Burroughs" *Barsoom* series of novels are the principal progenitor of this subgenre.

The simple answer is that the world of Unus Solum doesn't fit easily or readily into any one distinct subgenre. It does fit equally well into the two broad genres of science-fiction and fantastic adventure. It also falls into the subgenres of "lost-colony" stories and "planetary romance". yet overall there seems to be a patina of retro-futurism.

The old-school traditionalist would lean towards science-fiction, but would concede it does well as fantastic adventure. Yes there are clear elements of dieselpunk and cyberpunk, while airships usually connote steampunk, however, magnetically levitated airships aren't in that overheated category.

While it is possible to simply point that Unus Solum has elements of all these genres and subgenres, this doesn't prevent you from creating your own subgenre branding. So you could label it as "retrofuture-punk adventure" and no-one would be able to stop you. Of course, it might be simpler to call it, say, "Exoplanetary Adventure" on the grounds that Unus Solum is an exoplanet. This would avoid worrying about genre and subgenre distinctions. Labels are the least of your worries, just focus on the worldbuilding and the stories that go with it. Always have fun doing so.

Comment: @GalacticVikings Glad to be of help. Hope it clarifies your thinking.